# KieRemoteHttpRequestException: Unable to add char sequence to request body

Tags: java, http, jbpm, kie, kie-server

Could some one help with the below error.

I tried the option of setting -Dfile.encoding = UTF-8 env variable. This is occurring intermittently on average 3 of 5 requests its giving this error.

```
Caused by: org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequestException: Unable to add char sequence to request body
        at org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequest.initializeConnection(KieRemoteHttpRequest.java:927) ~[kie-remote-common-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequest.responseCode(KieRemoteHttpRequest.java:1326) ~[kie-remote-common-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequest.post(KieRemoteHttpRequest.java:719) ~[kie-remote-common-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:240) ~[kie-server-client-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:235) ~[kie-server-client-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.QueryServicesClientImpl.query(QueryServicesClientImpl.java:891) ~[kie-server-client-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        ... 62 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequest.openOutput(KieRemoteHttpRequest.java:1110) ~[kie-remote-common-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequest.initializeConnection(KieRemoteHttpRequest.java:924) ~[kie-remote-common-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequest.responseCode(KieRemoteHttpRequest.java:1326) ~[kie-remote-common-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.remote.common.rest.KieRemoteHttpRequest.post(KieRemoteHttpRequest.java:719) ~[kie-remote-common-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:240) ~[kie-server-client-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.makeHttpPostRequestAndCreateCustomResponse(AbstractKieServicesClientImpl.java:235) ~[kie-server-client-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
        at org.kie.server.client.impl.QueryServicesClientImpl.query(QueryServicesClientImpl.java:891) ~[kie-server-client-6.4.0.Final.jar:6.4.0.Final]
```

Comment: *"Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"* means the connection to the destination is refused. The host's IP address could be found, there was a route to that host, but there seemed to be no one listening for us.

Comment: Thanks Le Rutte, I was thinking same but if i call same service using spring boot it is working, this issue occurs only when use the war file and deploy in tomcat. That to it is intermittently.

Comment: Got it fixed, It was a proxy issue.Added proxy setting to system variable.
But i don't why it is intermittently happening.